# Batch forecasting using HoltWinters forecast

Tags: r, functional-programming, batch-processing, forecasting, holtwinters

I'm using Rob Hyndman's batch forecasting approach to forecast for multiple columns in a `dataframe`. My code is as follows:

```
require(forecast)

zips <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
zips <- zips[,-c(1,2)]
ns <- ncol(zips)

zips <- ts(zips, frequency = 12, start = c(2005,1), end = c(2014,12))
zips <- HoltWinters(zips, seasonal = "mult")

h <- 24

fcast <- matrix(NA, nrow=h, ncol=ns)
for(i in 1:ns) {
    fcast[,i] <- forecast.HoltWinters(zips[,i], h=h)
}

write(t(fcast), file="fcast.csv", sep=",",ncol=ncol(fcast))
```

Although it works just fine when using the regular `forecast` function, I keep getting the error

> [Error in zips[,i] : incorrect number of dimensions]

How do I get this `HoltWinters` forecast to run using this loop I have constructed here?

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your forecasts to list instead of a matrix. And also, `forecast.HoltWinters` function requires object of class `HoltWinters` which is produced by `HoltWinters` function that requires a vector as input. Apart from point forecasts, by default the `forecast.HoltWinters` function produces also the prediction interval bounds.

```
fcast <- list()

for(i in 1:ns) {

  zips_fit <- HoltWinters(zips[, i], seasonal = "mult")
  fcast[[i]] <- forecast.HoltWinters(zips_fit, h = h)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I'm also using similar kind of batch processing for Holts Winter forecasting method, but I use the function hw from forecast package created by Professor Rob J Hyndman. 
Anyhow for your question I prefer to use `$mean` in forecasting. i.e

```
fcast <- matrix(NA, nrow=h, ncol=ns) 
for(i in 1:ns) {
    fcast[,i] <- forecast.HoltWinters(zips[,i], h=h)`$mean`
}
```

Try this once!

Answer (score 0):

`hw()` function gives forecast values anyway. to get point forecast you may use `$mean` (as used in the following code). you could also use `seasonal = "additive"` or `seasonal = "multiplicative"` arguments.

Good luck

best

```
require(forecast)

    zips <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

    zips <- ts(zips, frequency = 12, start = c(2005,1), end = c(2014,12))

    ns <- ncol(zips)
    h <- 24

    fcast <- matrix(NA, nrow=h, ncol=ns)
    for(i in 1:ns) {fcast[,i] <- hw(zips[,i],h=h)$mean

    }

    write(t(fcast), file="fcast.csv", sep=",",ncol=ncol(fcast))
```